# How to make added buttons visible for the selected row in Wpf Datagrid

Tags: wpf

I have a Wpf Datagrid with edit,update and cancel buttons. Initially edit button is made visible, On click of edit button update and cancel button is made visible.

The issue here is when I click on edit button , update and cancel button are made visible for all the rows in the grid. I want it to be visible only for the selected row in the grid.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                     <StackPanel Name="Stkbuttons">
                           <Button Name="BtnEdit" Content="Edit" Width="Auto" Click="BtnEdit_Click" Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource                         FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=BtnEditVisibility}"></Button>
                          <Button Name="BtnUpdate" Content="Update" Width="Auto" Click="BtnUpdate_Click" Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource=                           {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=BtnUpdateVisibility}"></Button>
                           <Button Name="BtnCancel" Content="Cancel" Width="Auto" Click="BtnCancel_Click" Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource=                          {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=BtnCancelVisibility}"></Button>
                      </StackPanel>
                  </DataTemplate>
             </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty BtnEditVisibilityProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BtnEditVisibility", typeof(Visibility), typeof(OrderExecution));
     public Visibility BtnEditVisibility
     {
         get { return (Visibility)GetValue(BtnEditVisibilityProperty); }
         set { SetValue(BtnEditVisibilityProperty, value); }
     }

public static readonly DependencyProperty BtnUpdateVisibilityProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BtnUpdateVisibility", typeof(Visibility), typeof(OrderExecution));
     public Visibility BtnUpdateVisibility
     {
         get { return (Visibility)GetValue(BtnUpdateVisibilityProperty); }
         set { SetValue(BtnUpdateVisibilityProperty, value); }
     }

public static readonly DependencyProperty BtnCancelVisibilityProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BtnCancelVisibility", typeof(Visibility), typeof(OrderExecution));
     public Visibility BtnCancelVisibility
     {
         get { return (Visibility)GetValue(BtnCancelVisibilityProperty); }
         set { SetValue(BtnCancelVisibilityProperty, value); }
     }

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
          // By default display editButton
         BtnUpdateVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
         BtnCancelVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
     }

private void BtnUpdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
         BtnEditVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
         BtnUpdateVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
         BtnCancelVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
     }

 private void BtnEdit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
        BtnEditVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
         BtnUpdateVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
         BtnCancelVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

Comment: It'd probably be helpful to know just how you did this...

Answer (score 0):

Before enabling your buttons go to the parent of the clicked Edit button and get only his childs buttons (Update - Cancel) and change the visibility for only those two buttons.